# Can we measure the acceleration with Newton

Tags: acceleration

I have read before that

```
1 N = 1 m/s^2
```

And the m/s^2 is a unity for measuring the acceleration so i thought that we can represent acceleration in newton , can we say for example : this car acceleration is 4 N

Comment: That's not correct. 1 N = 1 kg m/s^2

Answer (score 1):

If you know the mass of the car, then you can use 
$$F=ma$$
to calculate the force given the acceleration or the acceleration given the force. It doesn't make much sense to use Newtons to measure acceleration, because $F$ Newtons is related to $a$ $\text{ms}^{-2}$ by $m$ kilograms. Your equation is only right if $m=1$ kg is understood.